# adding forloop result in c sharp

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm new in `C sharp`. I have a simple problem with for loop. but I don't know how to solve it. I have made loop Like This :

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        for (int starting = 0; starting < 10; starting += 3) {
            Console.WriteLine(starting);
        }
    }
}
```

// Result : 0 , 3 , 6 , 9.

I want to add all of the result.

Comment: Adding another variable and sum to it the value of starting one?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Steve comment, did you mean something like this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int starting = 0; starting < 10; starting += 3)
        {
            sum += starting;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum: [{0}]", sum);
    }
}
```

Updated based on the comments.

Comment: Sorry, but I mean like this.
The result is 0,3,6,9. And I add all of the result. So, 0+3+6+9, I get 18. Then I want the output is just 18, not 0,3,6,9. Thanks

Comment: @ShJalal if you want to display only sum result, you should move `Console.WriteLine` out of the for loop.

Comment: if I move it out of the for loop, can I still access starting variable ?

Comment: @ShJalal No. But you can declare `int starting = 0;` before the `for` loop. In this case the `for` loop will look like this: `for (starting = 0; starting < 10; starting += 3)` and you then can access `starting` variable outside the `for` loop as well. Remember: `for  ( initializationStep; conditionToStayInTheLoop; lastStatementInALoop ) { }`

Answer (score -1):

There is a shorter solution on the same task using LINQ:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => i % 3 == 0).Sum();

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```